# Cannot connect to socket.io server in subpath

Tags: react-native, docker, nginx, websocket, socket.io

### Issues

As the title, I can't connect to socket.io server when config it in a subpath

### Information

I have a server running at domain: https://mydomain.io

The server is running docker containers's name:

- api - port 8080/tcp - running java for RESTApi
- socket.io - port 3000/tcp  - running node.js socket.io
- nginx - port 0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, :::80->80/tcp

Here is my nginx config for socket.io:

```
    ...

    location /socketio/ {
        proxy_pass          http://socket.io:3000/;
        
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    Host $host;
        proxy_http_version  1.1;
        proxy_set_header    Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header    Connection "upgrade";

        add_header          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin" always;
        add_header          'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
        add_header          'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS' always;
        add_header          'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Accept,Authorization,Cache-Control,Content-Type,DNT,If-Modified-Since,Keep-Alive,Origin,User-Agent,X-Requested-With' always;
    }
}
```

Here my socket.io server:

```
const express = require("express");
const http = require("http");
const socketIO = require("socket.io");

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketIO(server, { path: "/socketio/" });

const PORT = 3000;

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Klubcoin chat socket.io server!");
});

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  socket.on("joinRoom", (room) => {
    socket.join(room);
  });

  socket.on("chatMessage", (room, message) => {
    io.to(room).emit("chatMessage", message);
  });
});

server.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

I can use Postman to make a GET request to the endpoint 'https://mydomain.io/socketio' and get the message "Klubcoin chat socket.io server!", So for sure my "socket.io" container can be reached.

Here is the socket.io-client code in my react-native project:

```
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';

let socketInstance;

const createSocketInstance = () => {
    return io('wss://mydomain.io', {
        path: '/socketio/'
    });
};

export const getSocketInstance = () => {
    if (!socketInstance) {
        socketInstance = createSocketInstance();
    }
    return socketInstance;
};
```

I even tried the Socket.io connect of Postman to test but I can't connect too